# jquery validate is not working with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-validate, element

jquery validate is not working with dynamic content

I use jquery to create tabs with new content.

```
var tabCounter = 2,
tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-    close'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
var tabContentHtml = $("#tabs-1").html();
```

Add new tabs when click button

```
$("#add_tab").click(function(){
    addTab();
});
function addTab() {
    var label = "Tab " + tabCounter,
        id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
        li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) );

    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
    tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    tabCounter++;
}
```

Validate Form into tabs. It work with tabs-1 but not work with tabs-2

```
  $("#Form").validate({
           rules:{
                name: "required",
                   messages:{
                        name: "Please enter your name"
                   },
           errorElement: "div",            
                   wrapper: "div",           
           errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                   offset = element.offset();
                   error.insertBefore(element)
                   error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
                   error.css('position', 'absolute');
                   error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
           },
           submitHandler: function(form) {
                   form.submit();
           }

    });
```

Code HTML

```
 <form id="Form" method="post" action="">       
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#tabs-1">Visa 1</a> 
        <!-- <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span> -->
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <table class="content-tabs">
        <tr class="fieldgroup">
            <td>Full Name</td>  
            <td><input type="text" class="txtName" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr></td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </div>
  </form>
```

How to validate content into tabs-2 ?

Comment: You should probably accept some of the answers to your other questions, you may get a better response.

Comment: And try this: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your new tab, you need to manually add rules to validate for the new content.  The easiest way is probably to use the [rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) method of the validation plugin.

At the bottom of your `addTab` function, you would do something like this:

```
$('#'+id).find('input').rules('add',{
    required: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be jquery is not aware of a dom update if you dont use live or on methods

try to put the validate method on an "on" click method like

```
$("#Form").on ('click',handler)
```

Please accept an answer as Laurence suggested

put like this

```
$("#Form").on("click", function(event){
      $(this).validate({
           rules:{
                name: "required",
                   messages:{
                        name: "Please enter your name"
                   },
           errorElement: "div",            
                   wrapper: "div",           
           errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                   offset = element.offset();
                   error.insertBefore(element)
                   error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
                   error.css('position', 'absolute');
                   error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
           },
           submitHandler: function(form) {
                   form.submit();
           }

    });
});
```

Comment: Please, You can write more clearly. I don't use method live() or ON;