# How to validate dynamic content using jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm having issues validating some dynamic content. The closest I have come to finding a similar problem is this:
[jquery-validate-is-not-working-with-dynamic-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170006/jquery-validate-is-not-working-with-dynamic-content)

My form is a basic form, enter name, email, phone etc. But there's this question "How many passengers?"
This is a `select` and depending on how many passengers you select, I use jQuery to create more fields based on this amount using this:

```
$('select.travellers').attr('name','Number of travelers').on('click', function() {
          var travellers = this.value; //On change, grab value
          var dom = "";
          for(var i = 0; i < travellers; i++){ //for 0 is less than travellers
              dom += '<label>Full Name</label>';
              dom += '<input type="text" name="FullName_'+i+'">';
              dom += '<label>Food&nbsp;requirements</label>';
              dom += '<select size= "0" name="Food Requiries_'+i+'"  tabindex="-1"  >
                      <option value="No pork">No pork</option>
                      <option value="Halal">Halal</option>
                      <option value="Food allergies">Food allergies</option>
                      <option value="Other">Other</option></select>';
          }
          $('.form_Additional').html(dom); //add dom into web page
        });
```

The output is an `input` field asking for the additional passenger name and a `select` asking for their food requirements

How do I validate these newly created elements? This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    //validation rule for select
    $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
      return arg != value;
     }, "Value must not equal arg.");


    //validate form
    $("#FORMOB7DC24203803DC2").on("click", function(event){
        $(this).validate({
            rules: {
                FullName:{
                    required: true  
                },
                FullName_0:{
                    required: true  
                },
                'Number of travelers':{
                    valueNotEquals: "Please select" 
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make this dynamic? Because this form allows for up to 30 passengers and I don't want to manually write in rules `FullName_0`, `FullName_1`, `FullName_2`  etc etc.

I added the rule `FullName_0` and it doesn't validate so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

note - simplified code for readability

Comment: have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you for that. Is there a way to make the rules dynamic? I don't want to add a rule in for FullName_0, FullName_1, FullName_2, FullName_3 etc

Comment: @ArunPJohny, i see that error Msg are seen, but where are you calling the error msg in jQuery? i dont see neither in dom :

Comment: @syd sorry what do you mean.. those messages are created by the validator framework

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did use this
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     //error.appendTo('.display_Error');
     //$('.display_Error').html(" ");
     $('.display_Error').html(error);
    },
But can't seem to get it to work properly. Also The form won't submit with the changes you suggested. Why is that?

Comment: it is because of the `debug: true`... you can remove it in the page

Comment: @ArunPJohny, goctha, Thanks Arun.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did remove the debug parameter but it's still not submitting. do I need to have a $(this).submit(); addded in?

Comment: @ArunPJohny nevermind. Forgot my client has slow hosting. Took a while to update...

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/5/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attributes to add the rules like

```
dom += '<input type="text" name="FullName_' + i + '" required>';
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/)

Comment: That is what I've done. I've had to do this to achieve the validation of the created elements:
rules: {
            FullName: {
                required: true
            },
            FullName_0: {
                required: true
            },
            FullName_1: {
                required: true
            }
        },
Based on your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/1/

Comment: if you see the fiddle in the answer, you can it with adding the `required` attribute

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand.

Comment: see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/5/).. it is done without adding rules like `FullName_0`, `FullName_1` etc...  that was your question wasn't it...

Comment: the fiddle you gave me has no rules, it's just rules:{}

Comment: but it is working the way you wants it, right? the rules are added as attributes to the element...

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. That does work but I have specific errors I need to check e.g email, date. and I want the errors to be more specific e.g passenger 1 needs to have name filled out, passenger 2 needs to have name filled out etc

Comment: you want to change the error messages? you can add all rules as attributes

Comment: Yes I can, I have found a way around. Thanks heaps for your help. Really got me out of a pickle

Comment: @AkiraDawson another way to handle it is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2fu7t2f3/6/

Comment: That works really well. I had issues doing it for the food requirements dropdown. I added this after the names: $els.find('input[name^="Food_Requiries_"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules("add", {
     valueNotEquals: "Please select" ,
     messages: {
      valueNotEquals: "Please select a food requirement" 
     }
    });
   });
But had no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '#FORMOB7DC24203803DC2', function(e) {
    validate();
});
```

This allows you to validate content added to page at any time.