# How I can maintain the sequence of beneficiaries generated with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a Will generating web application. For this I need to develop a system which allow the user to add multiple beneficiaries. 
I have written some code which is working for creation on new beneficiary but the issue is when a user deletes a beneficiary the sequence number doesn't work accordingly.

For example, User added 5 beneficiaries and he deletes the 3rd beneficiary the sequence number doesn't change. i.e. beneficiary 1, beneficiary 2, beneficiary 4, beneficiary 5. I want to sort this problem make them in sequence.

For my code please check this

https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadwaris/purvo4bn/5/

```js
$(document).delegate(".delBeneficiary", "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div = $(this).attr("id");
  var nmbr = div.replace(/\D/g, "");
  $("." + div).remove();
  bene--;

  //alert(nmbr);
});
var bene = 2;
$(".addBeneficiary").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addBeneficiary(bene);
  bene++;
});
$(document).delegate(".addBeneficiaryD", "click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addBeneficiary(bene);
  bene++;
});

function addBeneficiary(bene) {
  $("#beneficiaries").append(
    "<div class = 'bene" +
    bene +
    "'><h6 class = 'mt-3 mb-3'><b>Beneficiary <span class = 'bNmbr'>" +
    bene +
    "</span></b></h6>" +
    "<div class='form-group row'>" +
    "<label for='ename' class='col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2'><span class = 'pt-5'>Name</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>" +
    "<div class='col-sm-7'>" +
    " <input type='text' class='form-control p-1 mt-1' id='ename' name = 'ebname[]' placeholder='Name'>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<label for='enric' class='col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2'><span class = 'pt-5'>NRIC / Passport No.</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>" +
    "<div class='col-sm-7'>" +
    "<input type='text' class='form-control p-1 mt-1' id='enric' name = 'ebnric[]' placeholder='NRIC / Passport No'>" +
    "</div> " +
    "<label for='relationship' class='col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2'><span class = 'pt-5'>Relationship</span></label>" +
    "<div class='col-sm-7'>" +
    "<input type='text' class='form-control p-1 mt-1' id='Rrelationship' name = 'ebrelationship[]' placeholder='Relationship'>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class = 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 mt-2  text-right'>" +
    "<button class = 'btn btn-sm addBeneficiaryD ' id = 'bene" +
    bene +
    "' >Add</button>" +
    "<button class = 'btn btn-sm delBeneficiary ml-2' id = 'bene" +
    bene +
    "'>Delete</button>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div></div>"
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6 class='mt-3 mb-3'><b>Beneficiary <span class = 'bNmbr'>1</span></b></h6>
<div class="form-group row">

  <label for="ename" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>Name</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="ename" name='ebname[]' placeholder="Name" required='required' />
  </div>
  <label for="enric" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>NRIC / Passport No.</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="enric" name='ebnric[]' placeholder="NRIC / Passport No" required='required' />
  </div>
  <label for="relationship" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>Relationship</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="Rrelationship" name='ebrelationship[]' placeholder="Relationship" required='required' />
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 mt-2  text-right'>
    <button class='btn btn-sm addBeneficiary '>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='beneficiaries'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be careful, adding elements with same ID over and over again is not good, as for `id='enric'` or `id='bene'`...

Comment: Ok next time i will :)

Comment: Is it really important to have consecutive sequence numbers ? Those data will have to be saved in a database anyway, and then they'll get a unique id at the db level...

Comment: Yes with this user will get an idea he/she added all his/her beneficiaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start here

Much simpler code and removed the deprecated delegate

```js
function renum() {
  $(".beneficiary").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".bNmbr").text($(this).index()+1)
  })
}
$(".delBeneficiary").eq(0).hide()
$(document).on("click", ".delBeneficiary ", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".beneficiary").remove();
  renum();
});
$(document).on("click", ".addBeneficiary", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const beneCount = $(".beneficiary").length;
  let $bene = $(this).closest(".beneficiary").clone();
  $bene.find("input").each(function() { $(this).val("") }); // empty inputs
  $bene.find("[id]").each(function() {
    this.id += beneCount;
  })
  $bene.find(".bNmbr").text(beneCount + 1)
  $bene.appendTo("#beneficiaries")
  $(".delBeneficiary:gt(0)").show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='beneficiaries'>
  <div class="beneficiary">
    <h6 class='mt-3 mb-3'><b>Beneficiary <span class = 'bNmbr'>1</span></b></h6>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="ename" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>Name</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="ename" name='ebname[]' placeholder="Name" required='required' />
      </div>
      <label for="enric" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>NRIC / Passport No.</span><span class = 'text-danger'> *</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="enric" name='ebnric[]' placeholder="NRIC / Passport No" required='required' />
      </div>
      <label for="relationship" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class = 'pt-5'>Relationship</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="Relationship" name='ebrelationship[]' placeholder="Relationship" required='required' />
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 mt-2  text-right'>
        <button class='btn btn-sm addBeneficiary '>Add</button>
        <button class='btn btn-sm delBeneficiary ml-2'>Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I  have  already written code similar like  your's but the issue was changing  DOM data i.e. it clone everything including data inside input so i remove that code.

Comment: I have added a renumber and reset the content

Comment: yes it is working. thank you so much for your precious time :)

Comment: How I can implement validation on this by using JQuery validation plugin with just adding `required` attribute? it worked on first content but it doesn't work when i click on add button. It ignore the dynamic content just validate the first one. Again I need your help.

Comment: You should not need a jquery plugin if you have required.

Comment: Actually this is a form wizard so

Comment: So HTML5 required only works if you have a submit button. Your jQuery plugin is more complicated. You need to refresh the validation each time you add a field

Comment: How I can refresh it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536271/validate-dynamically-added-input-fields

Comment: In this answer they are changing the name attribute everytime when add button is clicked but in my case i have array it doesn't work on `Array` how i can make it work on array?

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try renumbering your entries every time you add or delete:

```
function renumber() {
    var i = 1;
    $('.bNmbr').each(function(){
        this.innerHTML = i;
        ++i;
    });
}
```

Can be combined with the code by mplungjan.

Comment: I added the renumber too AND a reset of cloned values

Answer (score 0):

This would be a complete code for you. I tried to make it easier for editing and removed duplicate ID creations:

```js
var bene = 1;

function correctNumbers() {
    $('.bNmbr').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(i + 1);
    });
};

$('body').on('click', '.addBeneficiary', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    bene++;
    addBeneficiary(bene);
});

$('body').on('click', '.delBeneficiary', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.bene').remove();
    correctNumbers();
});

function addBeneficiary(bene) {
    $("#beneficiaries").append('\
        <div class="bene" id="bene' + bene + '">\
            <h6 class="mt-3 mb-3"><b>Beneficiary <span class="bNmbr">' + bene + '</span></b></h6>\
            <div class="form-group row">\
                <label for="ename' + bene + '" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2">\
                    <span class="pt-5">Name</span>\
                    <span class="text-danger"> *</span>\
                </label>\
                <div class="col-sm-7">\
                    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="ename' + bene + '" name="ebname[]" placeholder="Name">\
                </div>\
                <label for="enric' + bene + '" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2">\
                    <span class="pt-5">NRIC / Passport No.</span>\
                    <span class="text-danger"> *</span>\
                </label>\
                <div class="col-sm-7">\
                    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="enric' + bene + '" name="ebnric[]" placeholder="NRIC / Passport No">\
                </div>\
                <label for="relationship' + bene + '" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2">\
                    <span class="pt-5">Relationship</span>\
                </label>\
                <div class="col-sm-7">\
                    <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="relationship' + bene + '" name="ebrelationship[]" placeholder="Relationship">\
                </div>\
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 mt-2  text-right">\
                    <button class="btn btn-sm addBeneficiary" id="add' + bene + '">Add</button>\
                    <button class="btn btn-sm delBeneficiary ml-2" id="delete' + bene + '">Delete</button>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    ');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h6 class='mt-3 mb-3'><b>Beneficiary <span class='bNmbr'>1</span></b></h6>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ename" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class='pt-5'>Name</span><span class='text-danger'> *</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="ename" name='ebname[]' placeholder="Name" required='required' />
    </div>
    <label for="enric" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class='pt-5'>NRIC / Passport No.</span><span class='text-danger'> *</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="enric" name='ebnric[]' placeholder="NRIC / Passport No" required='required' />
    </div>
    <label for="relationship" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label backgroundForm pt-2 pb-2"><span class='pt-5'>Relationship</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control p-1 mt-1" id="Rrelationship" name='ebrelationship[]' placeholder="Relationship" required='required' />
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11 mt-2  text-right'>
        <button class='btn btn-sm addBeneficiary '>Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='beneficiaries'>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a4du07r/)

Comment: Please use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of escaping newlines.  Or look at my solution for something more elegant than adding html strings

Comment: @mplungjan Does IE [support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah, IE does not support them, so even better to use clone :) Or transpile with Babel

Comment: How I can implement validation on this by using JQuery validation plugin with just adding required attribute? it worked on first content but it doesn't work when i click on add button. It ignore the dynamic content just validate the first one. Again I need your help.

Comment: Think that question has [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778722/how-to-validate-dynamic-content-using-jquery-validate-plugin)?